# How to find the elements greater than integer

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have dictionary below

`[{'id': 0, 'Title': 'The Land Girls', 'US Gross': 146083, 'Worldwide Gross': 146083, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 8000000, 'Release Date': 'Jun 12 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Gramercy', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 6.1, 'IMDB Votes': 1071}, {'id': 1, 'Title': 'First Love, Last Rites', 'US Gross': 10876, 'Worldwide Gross': 10876, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 300000, 'Release Date': 'Aug 07 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Strand', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'Drama', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 6.9, 'IMDB Votes': 207}, {'id': 2, 'Title': 'I Married a Strange Person', 'US Gross': 203134, 'Worldwide Gross': 203134, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 250000, 'Release Date': 'Aug 28 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Lionsgate', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'Comedy', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 6.8, 'IMDB Votes': 865}, {'id': 3, 'Title': "Let's Talk About Sex", 'US Gross': 373615, 'Worldwide Gross': 373615, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 300000, 'Release Date': 'Sep 11 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Fine Line', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'Comedy', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 13, 'IMDB Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Votes': 'null'}, {'id': 4, 'Title': 'Slam', 'US Gross': 1009819, 'Worldwide Gross': 1087521, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 1000000, 'Release Date': 'Oct 09 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Trimark', 'Source': 'Original Screenplay', 'Major Genre': 'Drama', 'Creative Type': 'Contemporary Fiction', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 62, 'IMDB Rating': 3.4, 'IMDB Votes': 165}, {'id': 5, 'Title': 'Mississippi Mermaid', 'US Gross': 24551, 'Worldwide Gross': 2624551, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 1600000, 'Release Date': 'Jan 15 1999', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'MGM', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Votes': 'null'}, {'id': 6, 'Title': 'Following', 'US Gross': 44705, 'Worldwide Gross': 44705, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 6000, 'Release Date': 'Apr 04 1999', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Zeitgeist', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'Christopher Nolan', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 7.7, 'IMDB Votes': 15133}, {'id': 7, 'Title': 'Foolish', 'US Gross': 6026908, 'Worldwide Gross': 6026908, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 1600000, 'Release Date': 'Apr 09 1999', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Artisan', 'Source': 'Original Screenplay', 'Major Genre': 'Comedy', 'Creative Type': 'Contemporary Fiction', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 3.8, 'IMDB Votes': 353}, {'id': 8, 'Title': 'Pirates', 'US Gross': 1641825, 'Worldwide Gross': 6341825, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 40000000, 'Release Date': 'Jul 01 1986', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'null', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'Roman Polanski', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 25, 'IMDB Rating': 5.8, 'IMDB Votes': 3275}, {'id': 9, 'Title': 'Duel in the Sun', 'US Gross': 20400000, 'Worldwide Gross': 20400000, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 6000000, 'Release Date': 'Dec 31 2046', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'null', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 86, 'IMDB Rating': 7, 'IMDB Votes': 2906}, {'id': 10, 'Title': 'Tom Jones', 'US Gross': 37600000, 'Worldwide Gross': 37600000, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 1000000, 'Release Date': 'Oct 07 1963', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'null', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 81, 'IMDB Rating': 7, 'IMDB Votes': 4035}, {'id': 11, 'Title': 'Oliver!', 'US Gross': 37402877, 'Worldwide Gross': 37402877, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 10000000, 'Release Date': 'Dec 11 1968', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Sony Pictures', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'Musical', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 84, 'IMDB Rating': 7.5, 'IMDB Votes': 9111}, {'id': 12, 'Title': 'To Kill A Mockingbird', 'US Gross': 13129846, 'Worldwide Gross': 13129846, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 2000000, 'Release Date': 'Dec 25 1962', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'Universal', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 97, 'IMDB Rating': 8.4, 'IMDB Votes': 82786}, {'id': 13, 'Title': 'Tora, Tora, Tora', 'US Gross': 29548291, 'Worldwide Gross': 29548291, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 25000000, 'Release Date': 'Sep 23 1970', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'null', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'Richard Fleischer', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Rating': 'null', 'IMDB Votes': 'null'}, {'id': 14, 'Title': 'Hollywood Shuffle', 'US Gross': 5228617, 'Worldwide Gross': 5228617, 'US DVD Sales': 'null', 'Production Budget': 100000, 'Release Date': 'Mar 01 1987', 'MPAA Rating': 'null', 'Running Time min': 'null', 'Distributor': 'null', 'Source': 'null', 'Major Genre': 'null', 'Creative Type': 'null', 'Director': 'null', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 87, 'IMDB Rating': 6.8, 'IMDB Votes': 1532}]`

How to find the movies which **IMDB Rating > 6** using DSL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html). Try out this below query

```
    {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "IMDB Rating": {
        "gt": 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can i pass "eq" for equal to

Comment: @sim you can use `gte` instead of `gt`

Comment: only which "eq" to 6, can i use eq